# referencing the variables in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following variables hard coded

```
<xsl:variable name="innerSubElement">
      <entry key="all">all</entry>
      <entry key="nD">nD</entry>
      <entry key="cC">cC</entry>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:variable name="nD">
       <nT colNumber="104"></nT>
      <dvI colNumber="105"></dvI>
      <mP colNumber="106"></mP>
      <qC colNumber="107"></qC>
    </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:if test="$innerSubElement/entry[@key = $innerElement]">
          <xsl:call-template name="subElementProcess">
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>

<xsl:template name="subElementProcess">

     <xsl:variable name="array">
          <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <v ><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></v>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
         <!-- <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($array)/v">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
        </xsl:for-each> -->

      <xsl:variable name="data">
        <xsl:if test="$nD/*[not(./name() = $array/v)]">

     <xsl:copy-of select="$nD/*[not(./name() = $array/v)]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="quantityContained">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$nD/*[not(./name() = $array/v)]"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($quantityContained)/*">

                <xsl:if test="local-name() = 'quantityContained'">

                    <measurementUnitCode colNumber="108"></measurementUnitCode>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

          </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="quantityContained">
     <xsl:for-each select="quantityContained">
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($data)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($data)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

now when i am traversing my xml file once i receive nD as a match from innerSubElement variable array. How do i how do i reference it at call the nD variable array where ever i have placed nD in call template directly instead i want to invoke it from the variable ?

Comment: I think you should show a bit more of your xslt, how do you "traverse the xml file"?

Comment: @StefanHegny i have edited it with what i am trying to do.

Comment: I think we have to go a step back you you try to follow [mcve]. This will increase the chance of getting a qualified answer and saves time on both sides.